# How to pinpoint what is slowing down my Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, refactoring

My Rails app runs fine in development mode (without caching) but in production has a hard time loading the :show view for the primary model. The log only shows SQL queries which add up to about 45ms, but the actual render time is about 15 seconds. I'm using acts_as_ferret and paperclip, but paperclip is only calling the after_save loop to no action. There are only 1 or 2 users online at the time, so I'm not thinking I've got a backed up queue, but I really can't narrow down what's hogging up the site. What can I do to more precisely measure server-side functions and see what is backing up the load time?

Things called in the :show view

- about 12 HABTM lists (types of tags, categories, etc.)
- Related videos found with acts_as_ferret
- HABTM comments for the videos

And that's really pretty much it. And how should I call HABTM as a Rails best practice? Right now I"m doing something like:

```
<%= @video.tags.map {|t| link_to t.name, path} %>
<%= @video.categories.map {|c| link_to c.name, path} %>
#etc....
```

I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do this, and I'm open to suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few tools to really pinpoint bottlenecks:

1. http://newrelic.com/
   will analyze things like db query time and ruby execution time on the server side
2. http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/
   will analyze things like response time, render time, and javascript on the client side

There's not a lot of given code to run with, but there's a few things that generally help in rails `find` or `where`:

1. use `:includes` to reduce number of queries.
2. use `:select` rather than selecting all columns

Great links on the subject:
http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2089
http://www.fortytwo.gr/blog/18/9-Essential-Rails-Tips
http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/thats-not-a-memory-leak-its-bloat/

Comment: Any way to include ALL habtm associations? The data is called quite a few times and to preload it all in one line of the controller would be good

Answer (score 0):

### Check the machine

Maybe other things running on that machine are the problem. Have you tried profiling the machine - for example, running `top` to check the CPU usage?